Why pml4 pointer address(uint64_t) is not loading in cr3 register?
I am using limine bootloader to load my x86_64 Kernel. I want to use my custom Paging so I made following codes.
Structers
#define PML4_INDEX(va)   (((va) >> 39) & 0x1FF)  // Bits 39-47
#define PDPT_INDEX(va)   (((va) >> 30) & 0x1FF)  // Bits 30-38
#define PD_INDEX(va)     (((va) >> 21) & 0x1FF)  // Bits 21-29
#define PT_INDEX(va)     (((va) >> 12) & 0x1FF)  // Bits 12-20
#define PAGE_OFFSET(va)  ((va) & 0xFFF)          // Bits 0-11


typedef struct page {
    uint64_t present   : 1;
    uint64_t rw        : 1;
    uint64_t user      : 1;
    uint64_t pwt       : 1;
    uint64_t pcd       : 1;
    uint64_t accessed  : 1;
    uint64_t dirty     : 1;
    uint64_t pat       : 1;
    uint64_t global    : 1;
    uint64_t ignored   : 3;
    uint64_t frame     : 40;
    uint64_t reserved  : 11;
    uint64_t nx        : 1;
} __attribute__((packed)) page_t;


typedef struct entry {
    uint64_t present   : 1;
    uint64_t rw        : 1;
    uint64_t user      : 1;
    uint64_t pwt       : 1;
    uint64_t pcd       : 1;
    uint64_t accessed  : 1;
    uint64_t dirty     : 1;
    uint64_t pat       : 1;
    uint64_t global    : 1;
    uint64_t ignored   : 3;
    uint64_t frame     : 40;
    uint64_t reserved  : 11;
    uint64_t nx        : 1;
} __attribute__((packed)) entry_t;


typedef struct pt {
    page_t pages[512];
} __attribute__((aligned(PAGE_SIZE))) pt_t;

typedef struct pd {
    uint64_t entry_t[512]; // Each entry have Physical addresses of PTs
} __attribute__((aligned(PAGE_SIZE))) pd_t;

typedef struct pdpt {
    uint64_t entry_t[512]; // Each entry have Physical addresses of PDs
} __attribute__((aligned(PAGE_SIZE))) pdpt_t;

typedef struct pml4 {
    uint64_t entry_t[512]; // Each entry have Physical addresses of PDPTs
} __attribute__((aligned(PAGE_SIZE))) pml4_t;

placement_address = 0x100000
mem_end_address   = 0x105000

initializing paging
void initialise_paging()
{  
    nframes = (mem_end_address - placement_address) / 0x1000;
    frames = (uint64_t *) kmalloc(INDEX_FROM_BIT(nframes)); // less of 4 kb memory aligned
    memset(frames, 0, INDEX_FROM_BIT(nframes));
    // Allocate and zero-initialize the PML4 table
    kernel_pml4 = (pml4_t *) kmalloc_a(sizeof(pml4_t), 1); // 4 kb memory aligned
    memset(kernel_pml4, 0, sizeof(pml4_t));
    current_pml4 = kernel_pml4;

    // Identity-map the physical memory up to `placement_address`
    uint64_t i = placement_address;

    while( i < mem_end_address) // increment 4kb i.e. 0x1000
    {
        // Kernel code is readable but not writeable from user space
        page_t *page = get_page(i, 1, kernel_pml4);
        alloc_frame(page, 0, 0);
        i += 0x1000;
    }
    
    switch_to_page_table(kernel_pml4);  // Enable paging
}


void switch_to_page_table(pml4_t *pml4) {
    // Update the global current PML4 pointer
    uint64_t physical_address = (uint64_t) pml4;

    // Load the physical address of the new PML4 table into CR3
    asm volatile("mov %0, %%cr3" :: "r"((uint64_t) physical_address) : "memory");

    // Enable paging by setting the paging (PG) bit in CR0
    // uint64_t cr0;
    // asm volatile("mov %%cr0, %0" : "=r"(cr0));  // Read CR0
    // cr0 |= 0x80000000;                          // Set the PG bit (bit 31)
    // asm volatile("mov %0, %%cr0" :: "r"(cr0));  // Write CR0
}

page_t *get_page(uint64_t address, int make, pml4_t *pml4) {
    uint64_t pml4_idx = PML4_INDEX(address);
    uint64_t pdpt_idx = PDPT_INDEX(address);
    uint64_t pd_idx = PD_INDEX(address);
    uint64_t pt_idx = PT_INDEX(address);

    // Resolve PML4 entry
    if (!(pml4->entry_t[pml4_idx] & 0x1)) { // Check if entry is present
        if (make) {
            pdpt_t *new_pdpt = (pdpt_t *) kmalloc_a(sizeof(pdpt_t), 1); // create a new pdpt with 4 kb aligned
            memset(new_pdpt, 0, sizeof(pdpt_t)); // Zero out memory for safety
            pml4->entry_t[pml4_idx] = ((uint64_t)new_pdpt & ~0xFFF) << 12 | 0x3; // pml4 will hold address of new_pdpt and make it present and writable
        } else {
            return NULL; // Entry not present and not creating
        }
    }

    pdpt_t *pdpt = (pdpt_t *)((pml4->entry_t[pml4_idx] >> 12 & ~0xFFF)); // create  pdpt from pml4->entry_t[pml4_idx]

    // Resolve PDPT entry
    if (!(pdpt->entry_t[pdpt_idx] & 0x1)) { // Check if entry is present
        if (make) {
            pd_t *new_pd = (pd_t *)kmalloc_a(sizeof(pd_t), 1); // making new pd with 4 kb aligned
            memset(new_pd, 0, sizeof(pd_t));
            pdpt->entry_t[pdpt_idx] = ((uint64_t)new_pd & ~0xFFF) << 12 | 0x3;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    pd_t *pd = (pd_t *)((pdpt->entry_t[pdpt_idx] >> 12 & ~0xFFF));

    // Resolve PD entry
    if (!(pd->entry_t[pd_idx] & 0x1)) {// Check if entry is present
        if (make) {
            pt_t *new_pt = (pt_t *)kmalloc_a(sizeof(pt_t), 1); // making new pt with 4 kb aligned
            memset(new_pt, 0, sizeof(pt_t));
            pd->entry_t[pd_idx] = ((uint64_t)new_pt & ~0xFFF) << 12 | 0x3;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    // Resolve Page Table
    pt_t *pt = (pt_t *)((pd->entry_t[pd_idx] >> 12 & ~0xFFF)); // Creating Page Table from pd->entry_t[pd_idx]

    // Resolve Page
    page_t *page =(page_t *) &pt->pages[pt_idx];
    if(!(page->present)){ // Check if entry is present
         if (make) {
            page = (page_t *) kmalloc_a(sizeof(page_t), 1); // making new page  with 4 kb aligned
            memset(page, 0, sizeof(page_t));
            alloc_frame(page, 1, 1); // Allocate frame for the page
        }else{
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    return page;
}

Here when I am trying to load address of pml4 pointer address in cr3 register the system crashed.
Here qemu.log

CPU Reset (CPU 0)
RAX=0000000000101000 RBX=0000000000000000 RCX=0000000000000000 RDX=000000000000002f
RSI=000000000000018b RDI=0000000000101000 RBP=ffff8000bff36fc0 RSP=ffff8000bff36fa8
R8 =000000000000000c R9 =0000000000000000 R10=0000000000000000 R11=0000000000000000
R12=0000000000000000 R13=0000000000000000 R14=0000000000000000 R15=0000000000000000
RIP=ffffffff800053ed RFL=00000292 [--S-A--] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00af9a00 DPL=0 CS64 [-R-]
SS =0010 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 0000000000000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 0000000000000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS64-busy
GDT=     ffffffff800099c0 00000027
IDT=     ffffffff80009a00 00000fff
CR0=80010011 CR2=ffffffff80009a80 CR3=0000000000101000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=0000000000000018 CCD=ffff8000bff36fa8 CCO=SUBQ
EFER=0000000000000d00
FCW=037f FSW=0000 [ST=0] FTW=00 MXCSR=00001f80
FPR0=0000000000000000 0000 FPR1=0000000000000000 0000
FPR2=0000000000000000 0000 FPR3=0000000000000000 0000
FPR4=0000000000000000 0000 FPR5=0000000000000000 0000
FPR6=0000000000000000 0000 FPR7=0000000000000000 0000
XMM00=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM01=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
XMM02=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM03=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
XMM04=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM05=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
XMM06=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM07=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
XMM08=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM09=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
XMM10=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM11=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
XMM12=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM13=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
XMM14=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM15=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
     3: v=03 e=0000 i=1 cpl=0 IP=0008:00000000000efb0a pc=00000000000efb0a SP=0010:0000000000000fc8 env->regs[R_EAX]=00000000000f6106
EAX=000f6106 EBX=000f3e0a ECX=00000000 EDX=00000cf9
ESI=00000000 EDI=00100000 EBP=00000000 ESP=00000fc8
EIP=000efb0a EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f6180 00000037
IDT=     000f61be 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=000f61c8 CCD=00009e34 CCO=SUBL
EFER=0000000000000000
check_exception old: 0xffffffff new 0xd
     4: v=0d e=001a i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:00000000000efb0a pc=00000000000efb0a SP=0010:0000000000000fc8 env->regs[R_EAX]=00000000000f6106
EAX=000f6106 EBX=000f3e0a ECX=00000000 EDX=00000cf9
ESI=00000000 EDI=00100000 EBP=00000000 ESP=00000fc8
EIP=000efb0a EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f6180 00000037
IDT=     000f61be 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=000f61c8 CCD=00009e34 CCO=SUBL
EFER=0000000000000000
check_exception old: 0xd new 0xd
     5: v=08 e=0000 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:00000000000efb0a pc=00000000000efb0a SP=0010:0000000000000fc8 env->regs[R_EAX]=00000000000f6106
EAX=000f6106 EBX=000f3e0a ECX=00000000 EDX=00000cf9
ESI=00000000 EDI=00100000 EBP=00000000 ESP=00000fc8
EIP=000efb0a EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f6180 00000037
IDT=     000f61be 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=000f61c8 CCD=00009e34 CCO=SUBL
EFER=0000000000000000
check_exception old: 0x8 new 0xd
Triple fault


The above log is showing CR3 have 0x0000000000101000 and also showing Triple fault. I have seen switch_to_page_table(kernel_pml4); is causing problem.
For debugging I have got following result :
pml4_idx = 0 pdpt_idx = 0 pd_idx = 0 pt_idx = 258
pml4 addr. = 0x101000 pml4.entries[pml4_idx] = 0x10300003
pdpt addr. = 0x103000 pdpt.entries[pdpt_idx] = 0x105000003
pd addr. = 0x105000   pd.entries[pd_idx] = 0x107000003
pt addr. = 0x107000   pt.entries[pt_idx] = 0x107810
page frame addr. = 0x109008

pml4_idx = 0 pdpt_idx = 0 pd_idx = 0 pt_idx = 258
pml4 addr. = 0x101000 pml4.entries[pml4_idx] = 0x10300003
pdpt addr. = 0x103000 pdpt.entries[pdpt_idx] = 0x105000003
pd addr. = 0x105000   pd.entries[pd_idx] = 0x107000003
pt addr. = 0x107000   pt.entries[pt_idx] = 0x107818
page frame addr. = 0x10B008

pml4_idx = 0 pdpt_idx = 0 pd_idx = 0 pt_idx = 258
pml4 addr. = 0x101000 pml4.entries[pml4_idx] = 0x10300003
pdpt addr. = 0x103000 pdpt.entries[pdpt_idx] = 0x105000003
pd addr. = 0x105000   pd.entries[pd_idx] = 0x107000003
pt addr. = 0x107000   pt.entries[pt_idx] = 0x107820
page frame addr. = 0x10E008


I don't understand, How mem_range = 0x105000 - 0x100000 = 0x5000 = 20 KB is creating 3 4KB page although it is different question and I also know that it is not liable for crashing the system.
Edit :
Full code link is [here](https://github.com/baponkar/KeblaOS]
I am unable to find or understand the problem present in the code so that it is not working although Limine Paging system works fine.
I have add debug option to check pml4, pdpt, pd, pt and page entries but not find anything wrong with those entries. I also checked switch_to_page_table(kernel_pml4); is causing problem. Also QEmu log file shows the root pml4 pointer directory physical address successfully loaded after that system going to crashed and reboot so cr3 register value changed.
So I am expecting to find the main problem present in the code which is making system crash problem.

I asked this previously. Are you sure you have committed the files you are using to your Github repository. When I look at your main branch the code you have here doesn't look like what is in Github
